# Can't set selected option from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a problem when trying to set selected option from javascript.
I created one select and added options with php from mysql like this:

```
<select class="form-control input-group-lg" name="progress" id="progress">
<?php
  if ($conn === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM progress";
  if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $progress_name = $row['name'];
        echo "<option>$progress_name</option>";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "<option>Fault!</option>";
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</select>
```

And then set selected option from javascript like this:

```
$('#progress').val("Value to set");
```

This method works fine and it sets selected option with that value which I want.

ANOTHER METHOD:

I have php file and I select data from database (MySQL) in json and then using ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data_control/orders/progress_select.php',
  type: 'get',
  method: "POST",
  data: {selected_value:selected_value},
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function (response) {
    var len = response.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var progress_name = response[i].progress_name;
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = progress_name;
      option.value = progress_name;
      var select = document.getElementById('progress');
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
});
```

Options are added successfully, but I can't set selected value in this way:

```
$('#progress').val("Value to set");
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, which means your `<option>` are only added *after* the server sends the results back to the client (and not when the client loads the page, as in your first example). They are probably not present at the time you are trying to set the value. Can we see your complete javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the value outside the success

Either do

```js
var select = document.getElementById('progress');
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var progress_name = response[i].progress_name;
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = progress_name;
  option.value = progress_name;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
select.value='Value to set'
```

OR

```js
var select = document.getElementById('progress');
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var progress_name = response[i].progress_name;
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = progress_name;
  option.value = progress_name;
  if (progress_name==='Value to set') options.selected = true;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Shorter alternative

```js
document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = response
 .map(({progress_name}) => `<option${progress_name === 'Value to set'?' selected' : ''} value="${progress_name}">${progress_name}</option>`)
 .join("")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution helped me a lot!